# Duplicate error messages in SSMS 17.4

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, ssms

I am having a problem with "exec" in SSMS 17.4 on Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU7-GDR) (KB4057119) - 13.0.4466.4 (X64).
I am getting duplicate messages from "exec". If I get a syntax error error message count gets incremented. As in exec mickeymouse gives me a procedure does not exist message. Then exec -mickeymouse gives me a syntax error, then exec mickeymouse gives me 2 error messages that the procedure does not exist etc. Then I can try for donaldduck and get the same count of duplicated messages. I have rebooted the DB server and my desktop. Any suggestions?
If I put a print statement in a proccedure and exec that procedure I get duplicates as well.

Comment: please provide examples of the commands you are running. "mickeymouse" and "donaldduck" don't help us to help you very well.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Maybe sharing some code would help? We can't see you screen and have no idea what you are talking about here.

Comment: It is not mickeymouse or donaldduck it is any time I have a syntax error, exec starts incrementing the output.

Comment: On this server we have another database with TDE enabled and the creditcard field in that database is using Always Encrypted. That's when this problem started.

Comment: From the command exec mickeymouse i get Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'mickeymouse'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'mickeymouse'.

Comment: If I get a third syntax error I will get 3 of the above messages as in:Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'mickeymouse'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'mickeymouse'.
Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'mickeymouse'.

Comment: If I create a table as in Create table test
(fld1 int) the a very simple stored procedure Create procedure pop_test
as insert into test values (1)
 print '1 value inserted' then exec pop_test. I get 1 record inserted but (1 row affected)
1 value inserted
1 value inserted
1 value inserted

Comment: Pushing it further the simple stored procedure Create procedure pop_test
as
 declare @fld int = 1
 insert into test values (@fld)
 print '1 value inserted' Errors out 3 times on the int = 1 and gives me 3 Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption errors.

Comment: But there is no encryption in this database. Though I know tempdb gets encrypted where Always Encrypted is used.

Comment: If I exec sp_spaceused I get the expected 2 resultsets in the results tab and "Commands completed successfully." in the messages tab.

Comment: If I push the simple stored procedure to CREATE PROCEDURE pop_test
AS
 INSERT INTO test VALUES (1)
 SELECT '1 value instered'
 PRINT '1 value inserted' and then exec pop_test. 1 record gets inserted.  On the Results tab I get "1 value inserted" but on the messages tab I get: (1 row affected)

(1 row affected)
1 value inserted
1 value inserted
1 value inserted
1 value inserted